# Copy-paste not working outside of debugger

Tags: c#, wpf

So basically my C# programs AvalonEdit.TextEditor copy paste functions perfectly when launched inside VS2013 trough either Release or Debug, however once I try to execute the generated .exe file anywhere on my computer (of course I have Avalons dll in the same folder, since without it wouldn't even launch obviously), nothing will happen with copy-paste. As far as I can tell, even when I select text in on the textbox, then press Ctrl + C, and attempt to ctrl v inside notepad it'll have cleared out my clipboard, instead of copying any selected text. Same goes, when I copy something from notepad, try and attempt to ctrl v into the textbox, it'll paste nothing. I've tried to work trough it with code:

```
if (e.Key == Key.C && (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control)
{
    NewEntryText.Copy();
    //Clipboard.SetText(NewEntryText.SelectedText);
} else if
 (e.Key == Key.K && (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control)
{
    MessageBox.Show("FT");
    //Clipboard.SetText(NewEntryText.SelectedText);
}
else if (e.Key == Key.V && (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control)
{
    NewEntryText.Paste();

    /*if (NewEntryText.SelectedText != null)
    {
        NewEntryText.Text = NewEntryText.Text.Replace(NewEntryText.SelectedText, Clipboard.GetText());
    }
    else
    {
    }*/
}
```

With no prevail, I also made it look for Ctrl + K, to see if it catches the key input at all, which it does for Ctrl + K, popping up a MessageBox properly. I've also tried to use Clipboard.GetText/SetText instead of Avalons direct copy paste functions, still will not work properly.

On top of that, I tried to use copy paste functions in every way possible with normal textboxes too, it seems like copy-paste is somehow globally dysfunctional throughout my application outside of debugger.

*Update 1: It's been a few days, I've tried almost everything I could think of. I seem to be unable to fix the problem by myself, hoping for someone with insight in this.

Comment: Have you tried this with building your .exe in *Build* and *Debug* mode and launching the .exe?

Comment: Yes, I have. Didn't make any difference.